# How to return the number of records in a join for a given month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE POSTS  (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    DATE      DATE NOT NULL,
    [Other stuff omitted]
);

CREATE TABLE TOPICS (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    [Other stuff omitted]
);

CREATE TABLE THETA (
    POST_ID INT NOT NULL,
    TOPIC_ID INT NOT NULL,
    WEIGHT FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

I have a query to sum the WEIGHT in THETA across all posts, grouped by date and topic ID:

```
SELECT THETA.TOPIC_ID as TopicID, POSTS.DATE as Date, SUM(THETA.WEIGHT) as Value
  FROM POSTS INNER JOIN THETA
  WHERE THETA.POST_ID=POSTS.ID
  GROUP BY YEAR(POSTS.DATE), MONTH(POSTS.DATE), TopicID;
```

This works as expected, giving results like this:

```
+---------+------------+---------------------+
| TopicID | Date       | Value               |
+---------+------------+---------------------+
|       0 | 2008-08-19 |   350.4930010139942 |
|       0 | 2008-09-18 |  1745.5010008439422 |
|       0 | 2008-10-03 |   1468.824001269415 |
|       0 | 2008-11-25 |   1079.579000659287 |
|       0 | 2008-12-11 |  1070.3860008455813 |
|       0 | 2009-01-24 |  1453.3730010837317 |
|       0 | 2009-02-20 |  1139.2920009773225 |
|       1 | 2008-08-19 |  288.09700035490096 |
|       1 | 2008-09-22 |  1307.5790000930429 |
|       1 | 2008-10-16 |  1050.1739999558777 |
|       1 | 2008-11-11 |   868.2280002105981 |
|       1 | 2008-12-18 |   897.6830000579357 |
|       1 | 2009-01-12 |  1148.5619999151677 |
|       1 | 2009-02-12 |   858.0710002686828 |
|       2 | 2008-08-19 |  415.83300026878715 |
...
```

However, I would like to normalize the Value by the number of posts in that month. For example, if there were 100 posts in the month `2008-08-19`, then the first result row would have a Value of 3.50493 and the eight result row would have a Value of 2.88097. The challenge is that the number of posts varies per month, so I'm not quite sure what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT t.TOPIC_ID as TopicID, p.DATE as Date, SUM(t.WEIGHT)/s.Month_CT as Value
FROM POSTS p
JOIN THETA t
  ON t.POST_ID = p.ID
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(DATE) as Yr, MONTH(DATE) as Mnth, COUNT(ID) as Month_CT
        FROM POSTS
        GROUP BY YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE)
       )s
  ON    YEAR(p.DATE) = s.Yr
    AND MONTH(p.DATE) = s.Mnth
GROUP BY YEAR(p.DATE), MONTH(p.DATE), TopicID;
```

Comment: This will normalize by posts per topic per month, not all posts per month

Comment: @Quassnoi Thanks, misssed the TopicID in the `GROUP BY` updated.

Comment: @GoatCO. Thanks for this. I gave it a try and get the following error: "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'THETA.TOPIC_ID' in 'field list'".

Comment: Ah, my whoops, I added table aliases and didn't update everywhere, try now.

Comment: I had to change the JOIN line to just say "JOIN (SELECT DATE, COUNT(ID) as Month_CT", because later you reference `s.DATE`. This runs successfully; I'm not verifying by hand that it produced the correct results.

Comment: Ah, missed that too, alternatively see update.  Miss these bits when can't test the query myself.

Comment: OK, I think this is working. Two quick questions: why is the `MAX` needed? And how come the dates are always exactly the same for the same year and month? For example, for topic ID 0, the result returns a date of "2008-09-18". But for topic ID 1, the result returns a date of "2008-09-22". I'm guessing this is the same year and same month, so everything is correct. I'm just curious as to why they would be different. Why wouldn't they all be "2008-09-01", for example?

Comment: The `MAX()` is only needed if you use the subquery where you `SELECT DATE` as that subquery returns multiple records per month (that's why you're seeing misc dates because of the change you made to the subquery as a result of my mistake on the `JOIN`), if you use the updated version where the subquery is grouped by year/month and the `JOIN` uses the yr/mnth alias then `MAX()` isn't needed.

Comment: ACtually, after experimentation, it seems like the misc dates is caused by the "p.DATE as Date" in the SELECT clause. The date that's being shown in the results is the date of the first record found. If I change that to "MIN(p.DATE) as Date", then it's usually of the form "2008-09-01", i.e., at the beginning of the month. Anyway, it seems to be working nicely now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.topic_id TopicID,
        CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-01') AS Date
        SUM(t.weight) / cnt as NormalizedValue
FROM    (
        SELECT  YEAR(date) y,
                MONTH(date) m,
                COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    posts
        GROUP BY
                y, m, cnt
        ) p
JOIN    posts p
ON      p.date >= '0000-01-01' + INTERVAL y YEAR + INTERVAL m - 1 MONTH
        AND p.date < '0000-01-01' + INTERVAL y YEAR + INTERVAL m MONTH
JOIN    theta t
ON      t.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY
        y, m, t.topic_id
```